# Running java.exe from Windows cmd.exe

Tags: java, windows, cmd

I want to run `java -jar` from the JDK directory on my system:

```
D:\Users\djpastis\Downloads\fmw_12.2.1.4.0_wls_Disk1_1of1>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\bin\java
```

but I have this error, even the path is OK

```
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: You should be using this syntax, `"%ProgramFiles%\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\bin\java.exe" -jar "F:\ull\Path To\filename.jar"` In your case, if `filename.jar` is in `D:\Users\djpastis\Downloads\fmw_12.2.1.4.0_wls_Disk1_1of1` as that is clearly your current directory, you could just use `"%ProgramFiles%\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\bin\java.exe" -jar "filename.jar"`.

Comment: @Compo, I have been multiple places wherre Microsoft apps would be installed to `"%ProgramFiles%",`  but most third-party apps (7-Zip, Beyond Compare, git, etc.) would be installed to a `D:\Program Files" directory. How would you deal with that?

Comment: I wouldn't use the standard location variable `%ProgramFiles%` @lit, _or I may parse the registry user shell folders to determine the default location first_. In this specific case however, the OP used `'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command…`, which meant that the standard default would generally be okay! I will say however, that modern Windows Operating Systems, by default install to the drive allocated to `C:`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paths containing special characters, such as a SPACE, must be quoted. Microsoft put a SPACE characters in there for you. :-) The only reliable, safe way is to always quote paths.

```
"%ProgramFiles%\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\bin\java.exe"
```

Comment: @Compo is right, the enviromment variable should (must) be used.